# How to automaticaly fill a foreign key when a row is inserted in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys

I am currently working under postgres 14.
I got two tables customers and contacts, and i want to automatically find the customer_id from the customer name when i add a new contact in the table contacts.

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
   customer_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY(customer_id)
);

CREATE TABLE contacts(
   contact_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   customer_id INT,
   contact_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
   PRIMARY KEY(contact_id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_customer
      FOREIGN KEY(customer_id) 
      REFERENCES customers(customer_id)
);

INSERT INTO customers(customer_name) VALUES('my_first_customer')
```

So from here i want to do something like that  :

```
INSERT INTO contacts(customer_id, contact_name ) VALUES('my_first_customer',"thomas")
```

and i want to get this result in contacts table :

| contact_id | customer_id | contact_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | "thomas" |

i tried to make a function to change the value from name to id but get an error of type.
Because the the type error is catch before the trigger. Here is my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_id_fct() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $get_id_fct$
DECLARE val_id INTEGER;
BEGIN 
SELECT customer_id INTO val_id FROM customers WHERE customers.customer_id = NEW.customer_id;
NEW.customer_id := val_id; 
RETURN NEW
END
$get_id_fct$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER get_id
BEFORE INSERT ON contacts
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE get_id_fct();'
```

Is their a way around that ? or specific method to do this task that i don't know about ?
I am quite a beginner at SQL.

Comment: 1) I'm guessing it is failing before the trigger as you are trying to insert a string `'my_first_customer'` into an `integer` field. 2) `customers.customer_id = NEW.customer_id;` is not going to work as `customers.customer_id` is an `integer` and `NEW.customer_id` is a string. If you get  past 1) then `customers.customer_name = NEW.customer_id;` might work. 3) I think you need to think about what you are doing, namely provide the actual `customers.customer_id`.

Comment: Yes it is failing because i am trying to insert a string into a an integer field, even thought the trigger is before the insert which is a bit weird to me. Anyway their should be a way around that , i should not have to make a querry before every insert to find the customer_id related to the new contact. Or at least i should be able to make function doing that for each insert.

Comment: Postgres version? Do you *know* that there is a matching entry in table `customers`? Or is it *INSERT-or-SELECT*? Can there be concurrent write load, possibly writing rows for the same customer?

Comment: Type validation is done before the trigger is run. Since a contact is a child of a customer whatever form you are using to enter the data should already have the `customer_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a subquery in insert statement

```sql
INSERT INTO contacts(customer_id, contact_name ) VALUES (
(select customer_id from customers where customer_name = 'my_first_customer') ,'thomas');
```

This query will fail if there is more than one customer with given name, and insert a null value for customer_id if there is no customers with given name

Different approach (proposed by @wildplasser)

```sql
INSERT INTO contacts(customer_id, contact_name ) 
select customer_id,'thomas' from customers where customer_name = 'my_first_customer';
```

In this case, when there is no customer with given name, no row will be created. When there is more than one customer with given name, for each of them record will be created.

Or you can create view with `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

```sql
create view v_contacts as 
select customer_name, contact_name from customers 
  join contacts on customers.customer_id = contacts.customer_id;
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION emp () RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    
  INSERT INTO contacts(customer_id, contact_name ) 
    VALUES((select customer_id from customers where customer_name = 
       NEW.customer_NAME),NEW.contact_NAME);
    
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER v_contactst
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON v_contacts
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION emp();
```

Insert statement

```sql
INSERT INTO v_contacts(customer_name, contact_name ) VALUES('my_first_customer','thomas')
```

And just a note, that columns `customer_name` and `contact_name` are not unique so this code is not safe and throw error if `customer_name` didn't exists or there is more than one record with this `customer_name`

Comment: NOTE: you dont need the `values(...)` Just a `SELECT ...` will do.

Comment: Yep. It can be done both ways. But there will be two differences. First: if there will be 2 customers with the same name then my insert throw an error, and select do the insert of 2 rows. Second: if there was no customer with that name your solution insert no rows, and my insert a row with null value. So it's better first confirm an expected behaviour in those scenarious.

Comment: Thanks you for your detailed answer.  The subquerry is a good idea. I wanted to make my question real simple but in my real code , i also test if the customer is in the table customers and dont add the contact to contacts if not. Any idea to do both ?

Comment: In that case (contasts should be added only if customer exists, and there is at mous one customer with given name, solution proposed by @wildplasser will work. I've updated my answer
`